# Agreement/Contract for sharing revenue from mobile app

Tags: contract-law, digital-contract

One LLC (company A) building a mobile application for another LLC (company B).
We agreed that company B does not pay me anything to company A but they will share revenue – 50/50 from ads and in-app purchases.

What type of contract I can use?

Where I can find an agreement template for such case?

Comment: If that's all you want them to agree to, just write that sentence down using the names of the companies and get them to agree to it either on paper or digitally. It sounds like you know what you want. Hire a lawyer do write a simple contract if it's more complex or there's a lot of money involved.

Answer (score 2):

> What type of contract I can use? Where I can find an agreement template for such case?

Contracts are not classified in the way you seem to have in mind. A contract just needs to be reasonably clear about the parties' rights and duties.

Among other characteristics, the contract will preferably be self-contained, reflect the parties' intent, have no material ambiguities, and contain provisions that would apply in the event that a party breaches the contract.

Don't think about searching for templates. A template is very unlikely to fit your particular needs. Instead, you should read contracts and ask yourself which ideas you read would advance your business purpose(s) and be legally sound. When drafting your contract, avoid verbosity and copycat legalese that needlessly obfuscate the parties' intent.

You might want to get acquainted with the [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](https://www.fbcoverup.com/docs/library/1981-Restatement-Second-of-Contracts-1981.pdf). That resource embodies the principles of contract law as applied in the US and has a multitude of similarities with the contract law of many other countries.